# Rewrite URL in YII with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I need to rewrite the following URLS

site.com/events/?event=test

to read like

site.com/events/test

I'm fine with doing this either in htaccess or in the urlManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/events` is your controller class, and `/test` is your parameter for the index action:

```
class EventController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex($event) {
```

Add this rule to your urlManager:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules' => array(
        'event/<event>' => 'event/index',

        ...
```

This will automatically map `test` in the url `/events/test` to the parameter `$event` in the index action.

```
    public function actionIndex($event) {

        echo $event; // produces "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

`htaccess` should be:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on the engine:

RewriteEngine on

# Do not perform redirects for files and directories that exist:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For everything else, redirect to index.php:

RewriteRule . index.php
</ifModule>
```

urlmanager should be:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'showScriptName'=>false, // removed index.php with .htaccess
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
           'test' => 'site/test' // Where controller/view
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on htaccess with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^events/$ /events/%1/? [R=302,L]
```

The above should work (changing `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect works properly).